Related to CDF of product of two independent Gamma random variables
I am working on a topic wherein I came across the following expression:
$P_1 = Pr(X<\phi)$ ----(1)
where $X$ is a random variable
And $X = h_0\cdot h_1$, such that $h_0\sim \text{Gamma}(m_0, \frac{\Omega_0}{m_0}), h_1\sim \text{Gamma}(m_1, \frac{\Omega_1}{m_1})$, where $m_0,m_1$ are shape and $\Omega_0, \Omega_1$ are spread parameters.
Note that both $h_0$ and $h_1$ are independent.
I understood that in equation (1), we have to basically find CDF of random variable $X$. But my query is how to find CDF when we have product of two Gamma random variables?
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Are $h_0$ and $h_1$ independent?

Thanks a lot mam for your reply...Yes $h_0$ and $h_1$ are independent...

You have to edit the question to say that they  are independent. That is important since not all random variables are independent.

I had edited the question and made required changes,,,,

It's quite hard to get an explicit formula for CDF of a product of Gamma r.v.s.
One of the ways is to use the Mellin transform, which has a great condition, that if you have 2 random variables, then their Mellin transformation of the product of those 2 r.v.s will be the product of two separate Mellin transformations:
$$\mathcal{M}_{h_{0}h_{1}}(x) = \mathcal{M}_{h_{0}}(x) \mathcal{M}_{h_{1}}(x).$$
Another way is to analyze product convolution integral (maybe some asymptotic analysis):
$$F_{h_{0}h_{1}}(x)
= \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}F_{h_{0}}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)f_{h_1}\left(y\right){\rm d}y $$

Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.
